# Firebase Web SDK createUserWithEmailAndPassword not logging in users after creation

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase email/password authentication.
This provider is activated for this project in Firebase console.
I'm using the Web SDK, and it is properly configured.

I have a form to signup that prompts the user to enter an email and a password to signup and authenticate.

`firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)`

is called when the user is signing up. The user is then directed the next step to fill his/her profile.

At this point

```
fb.auth.onAuthStateChanged(fbUser => {
if (fbUser) {
   console.log('Logged in. User is: ', fbUser)
} else {
   console.error('not logged in')
}
})
```

returns 'not logged in' while the user should be logged in according to the Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)

Comment: Firebase version 5.5.8

Comment: Hmm... that sounds weird. Can you reproduce it in a site like jsbin or stackblitz, so I can have a look?

Comment: The only way I can see this happening is if the "next step" is a separate page (so a reload). In that case `onAuthState` should fire twice: first with no user, and then later (once the user token is validated) with the actual user.

Comment: It's not a reload. I'm using a stepper. So everything is happening on the same page.

Comment: Agree that this is weird as there is a call to `sendEmailVerification()` in the callback section of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword ` which is working as newly created users are receiving the email to confirm their email address.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I work in SF too. So might be easier to check the code directly around a coffee as reproducing a complex signup/signin sequence might be tricky

Comment: Looking carefully at the console, just noticed that the object user created before being "deleted" is only containing a refreshToken